# Verify whether or not expression is true or not for z>0

Tags: logarithms

I need to verify whether or not the below expression is true or not for $z>0$.
I'm trying to understand the rules of logarithms but I can't figure out how to apply it myself or where to even begin.

$$\log_5 (z)+\log_{25} (z)= \frac{3}{2}\log_5 (z)$$

Thank you for your help

Comment: Was the second term supposed to read $\log_{25}(z)$?  If so, then the equation is valid.

Comment: Assuming my interpretation is correct...suppose $\log_5(z)=x$.  That means that $5^x=z$.  Now suppose that $\log_{25}(z)=y$.  That means $25^y=z$.  But $25^y=5^{2y}\implies 2y=x\implies y=\frac x2$.  Thus $\log_{25} (z)=\frac {log_5(z)}2$

Comment: Thanks, fixed! Can you please explain why it is valid?

Comment: I just did.  Can you follow my comment?

Comment: Thank you. Is the $^{2y}$ there because $5^2 =25$? Also why does $x$ become $2y$? What happened between $25^y$ and $5^{2y}$ to get that?

Comment: Logarithms are simply the inverse of exponents and all the rules apply "in reverse".  To get a feel you can raise 5 to each side of the equation to see what happens but that isn't how you should solve it.  The trickiest part for this particular problem is to recognize $\log_{25}z = \frac 12\log_5 z$ because $\log_{25}z =c \implies 25^c=z \implies 5^{2c}=z\implies \log_5 z = 2c $.

Comment: $25^y=(5^2)^y=5^{2y}$.  Since $5^x=25$ and $5^{2y}=25$ we have $5^x=5^{2y}$.  It's a very useful property of exponentials that they only take each positive value once.  Therefore $5^x=5^{2y}\implies x=2y$.

Comment: Then just use the rules $k*\log_a z = \log_a z^k $ and $\log_a x + \log_a z = \log_a xz $.  Use those three rules and... you can't go wrong.

Comment: Thanks I now understand how you got $\frac{log_5(z)}{2}$. What happens with $\frac{3}{2}log_5(z)$

Comment: To your last question:  For any $A$ we have $A+\frac A2=A +\frac 12 A=\frac 32 A$.  Here we have $\log_5 (z) + \frac 12 \log_5(z)=\frac 32 \log_5 (z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments...

Let's prove: $$\log_{25}(z)=\frac 12 \log_5(z)$$

To see that:  suppose $\log_5 (z)=x$.  That means $z=5^x$. Now suppose that $\log_{25}(z)=y$.  That means $z=25^y$  But $$25^y=5^{2y}=5^x\implies 2y=x \implies y =\frac 12x $$

And that last equality was what we wanted.

Comparison shows that we have established the equality posed in the original question.